# How to Sign OTA Files for Blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, cordova, blackberry-webworks, ota

How do I sign blackberry files in the OTAInstaller folder? I am using phone gap and I have a

`\build\OTAInstall` folder that contains 1 jar file and a whole lot of .cod files.

How do I sign those cod files?

I followed  [this tutorial](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_publishing/Signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html)  on how to setup signing but I don't know how actually run it to sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After following the steps within that [tutorial](https://bdsc.webapps.blackberry.com/html5/documentation/ww_publishing/Signing_setup_smartphone_apps_1920010_11.html) go to...

https://build.phonegap.com/people/edit#pane=signing

Then add BlackBerry Signing key to Phonegap

---

CSK file and DB file can be found at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\bin
```

sigtool.csk

sigtool.db

Set BlackBerry Signing Keys as default, run build again.

---

This is what my signing page looks like after setting a key as default.

[image]

Comment: What does that phonegap site do? It seems to want you to upload the files to github but I am unsure for what reason. How do I set the blackberry signing keys as default?

Comment: I found this. https://build.phonegap.com/docs/blackberry-keys an done that but now I upload the zip to github? Do I included everything like OTA folder and such?

Comment: I've updated my answer to show what my profile/signing page looks like after having a BlackBerry signing key set to default.

Comment: If you have a signing key set as default just re-build the application using which ever method you had originally used. If you are accessing Phonegap via your Account, then Phonegap should automatically sign the application.

Comment: I just used this- ant blackberry load-simulator. How does it know to contact phonegap site and get into my account? How do I verify if they been signed?

Comment: Here is a quick screenshot of bulding via the website http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mhr3GPZMnGc , if you do it right you should be able to download a folder containing a .alx .cod .csl and .cso , also if its done right you will be able to open the .cod in a BlackBerry Simulator.

Comment: Ok. So I have to use the phonegap build site and upload my file to that site in order to use OTA (no other way)? I noticed when I do my build it does make that zip file for me and that is what I uploaded. I get that bar code thing and I can download standardinstall.zip. Going to try the simulator now.

Comment: You can use any method as long as you sign in. I use a method built into Dreamweaver, others use command line. Not sure how to sign in with your particular method.

Comment: Do you have examples of how to do it by command line? Would they just host it on their own internal site or whereever they want to have it up for download.

Answer (score 0):

Go in your command line to the /bin dir of the webworks sdk, for example
C:\Program Files (x86)\Research In Motion\BlackBerry WebWorks SDK 2.3.1.5\bin

then run the signature tool:
java -jar SignatureTool.jar

open any of your .cod files and use 'request signature', it will sign both your standard and otainstall files

make sure to run the tool with java 6, not java 7, it crashes on the later